Disable links properties on input object Spring boot 3 webflux openapi and HATEOAS
I created a Spring boot 3 with webflux application, on top of that I added opanapi and contract first with swagger, I activated also HATEOAS in openapi because as model are generated on install with maven, I could not use hateoas plugin.
The issue I have it add links object not only on output objects, but also on input that we totally don't need, this input is used in my application for third api call that not understand "links". The first solution would be simply create a new object and mapper, but for the future maybe it can cause issue with apis, so I want to remove links objects from input object how I can do ?
my plugin configuration:
  <plugin>
            <groupId>org.openapitools</groupId>
            <artifactId>openapi-generator-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>7.4.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>generate</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <inputSpec>${project.basedir}/swagger.yaml</inputSpec>
                        <generatorName>spring</generatorName>
                        <library>spring-boot</library>
                        <apiPackage>com.telr.tokenization.api</apiPackage>
                        <modelPackage>com.telr.tokenization.core.entities</modelPackage>
                        <supportingFilesToGenerate>false</supportingFilesToGenerate>
                        <configOptions>
                            <disallowAdditionalPropertiesIfNotPresent>true
                            </disallowAdditionalPropertiesIfNotPresent>//not working
                            <hateoas>true</hateoas>
                            <reactive>true</reactive>
                            <interfaceOnly>true</interfaceOnly>
                            <skipDefaultInterface>true</skipDefaultInterface>
                            <useJakartaEe>true</useJakartaEe>
//I tested this not working                                
<additionalModelTypeAnnotations>
                                @com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude(com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
                            </additionalModelTypeAnnotations>
                        </configOptions>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

example of yaml:
    paths:
  /v1/tokens:
    post:
      tags:
        - Network token
      summary: Create network token
      description: Create network token
      operationId: createNetworkToken
      requestBody:
        description: Create a new network token in app
        content:
          application/json:
            schema:
              $ref: '#/components/schemas/Card'
        required: true
      responses:
        '201':
          description: OK
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                $ref: '#/components/schemas/NetworkTokenInformationResponse'
        '400':
          description: Bad Request
        '401':
          description: Unauthorized
        '500':
          description: Internal server error
  /v1/tokens/{gatewayToken}:
    get:
      tags:
        - "Network token"
      summary: "Retrieve token"
      description: "Returns a network token"
      operationId: "getToken"
      parameters:
        - name: gatewayToken
          in: path
          description: Gateway token generated in the network tokenization process
          required: true
          schema:
            type: string
      responses:
        "200":
          description: OK
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                $ref: '#/components/schemas/NetworkTokenInformationResponse'
        '400':
          description: Bad Request
        '401':
          description: Unauthorized
        '404':
          description: Token not found
        '500':
          description: Internal server error
components:
  schemas:
    NetworkTokenInformationResponse:
      type: object
      required:
        - gatewayToken
      properties:
        gatewayToken:
          type: string
        token:
          $ref: '#/components/schemas/NetworkToken'
    NetworkToken:
      type: object
      properties:
        enrollmentId:
          type: string
        tokenReferenceId:
          type: string
        dPan:
          type: string
        expMonth:
          type: string
        expYear:
          type: string
    Card:
      type: object
      required:
        - number
        - expirationMonth
        - expirationYear
      properties:
        number:
          type: string
        expirationMonth:
          type: string
        expirationYear:
          type: string
        securityCode:
          type: string

here the object generated in input that I totally don't need

Any idea how I can suppress this links object form all input objects ?
then pom.xml configuration:
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb-reactive</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webflux-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openapitools</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind-nullable</artifactId>
            <version>0.2.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.swagger.core.v3</groupId>
            <artifactId>swagger-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.21</version>
        </dependency>


Finally, i did not modified directly the object itself, but for serialization i added this following configuration in the pom.xml to modify generated class with annotations
  <plugin>
            <groupId>org.openapitools</groupId>
            <artifactId>openapi-generator-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>7.4.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>generate</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <inputSpec>${project.basedir}/swagger.yaml</inputSpec>
                        <generatorName>spring</generatorName>
                        <library>spring-boot</library>
                        <apiPackage>com.telr.tokenization.api</apiPackage>
                        <modelPackage>com.telr.tokenization.core.entities</modelPackage>
                        <supportingFilesToGenerate>false</supportingFilesToGenerate>
                        <configOptions>
                            <additionalModelTypeAnnotations>@lombok.Builder @lombok.AllArgsConstructor @lombok.EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
                                @com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude(com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY)
                            </additionalModelTypeAnnotations>
                            <hateoas>true</hateoas>
                            <reactive>true</reactive>
                            <interfaceOnly>true</interfaceOnly>
                            <skipDefaultInterface>true</skipDefaultInterface>
                            <useJakartaEe>true</useJakartaEe>
                        </configOptions>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

Indeed when i send this object in josn it will be cleaned for all null and empty object or list that what i need.
